# Why i create request permission location in framework alert not show long time

Tags: ios, swift, permissions, location, core-location

it show about 3 sec and dismiss

but when i create in normal class it show all time then user tap to answer Allow/not Allow

```
public class Location: NSObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate{
    public var locationManager = CLLocationManager()

    public func RequestLocation(){
        self.locationManager.delegate = self
        if CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == .notDetermined {
            self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        }

        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    }
}
```

---

EDIT - Added OP's code to show `Location` instantiation

```
import UIKit 
import DemoLocation 
class ViewController: UIViewController { 
    deinit { 
        print("deinit") 
    } 

    let location = Location() 
    override func viewDidLoad() { 
        super.viewDidLoad() 
        location.RequestLocation() 
    } 
}
```

Comment: From what thread you are calling this method ?

Comment: You need to make sure your instance of `Location` is being retained

Comment: Can you show the code used to create a `Location`?

Comment: import UIKit
import DemoLocation

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    deinit {
        print("deinit")
    }
    
    let location = Location()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        location.RequestLocation()
    }
}

Comment: when alert permission popup instance of class location is deinit

Comment: If location instance is deallocated, that must mean `ViewController` is also deallocated. You

Comment: i try to create more function to print string in class location ,It's fine work and not deinit

Answer (score 0):

This is because as soon as the `CLLocationManager` is released the dialog immediately disappears.

You should save the reference to `locationManager` via instance or as static variable

To overcome this issue you must change the `CLLocationManager` to exist on class vs the current instance to be released with the class.

For more help on `CLLocationManager` see [Apple API Reference](https://developer.apple.com/reference/corelocation/cllocationmanager)

Comment: `locationManager` as an instance variable is fine, The problem seems to be that the instance of `Location` isn't being retained anywhere.

Comment: He should have a reference to the locationManager on the static or instance